# Efficient and scalable Database design for chat application

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am building a chat application for private as well as group chat. I came up with a design as:

**design1:**

```
User:
id

Message:
id
sender_id (F - > user)
receiver_type [0 - group, 1 - user]
receiver_user [can be null] (F -> user)
receiver_group [can be null] (F -> group)
message
timestamp

Group:
id

Group_Users:
group_id (F -> group)
user_id (F -> user)
```

But later on I have come up with another design.

***design2***:

```
User:
id

Group:
id
is_private (1 - user, 0 - group )

Group_Users:
group_id (F -> group)
user_id (F -> user)

Message:
sender_id (F -> user)
receiver_id (F -> group)
message
timestamp
```

Explanation: For a private chat I would group two users. And the checking is done through Group's `is_private`.

***Which among the two is efficient and scalable ??***

Comment: @downvoter please comment the reason for downvoting this question.

Comment: IMO, this can be easily done on client side you dont need much complicated design on your database just simple user and nessage storage but in group chat issue client side can handle it very will

Comment: @arnoldemzi Please do read the question carefully. How does a client side handle group chat? What do you mean by simple user and message storage? And why is the above design complicated?

Comment: @StreetwayFun as of your design, design2 is the efficient one. design1 gives an extra overhead of adding  `receiver_type`, everytime there is a message to a group or a user. Your design2 approach appears to be perfect.

Comment: Hi. Two designs, no spec, just "application for private as well as group chat". You give no basis by which to judge.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best".

Comment: Show us the `SELECTs` for each case.  In doing that, you may answer the question yourself.